# run vagrant provisioner *after* first run

Tags: proxy, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to get a provisioner to run *after* the first vagrant up. Is there a flag or something that I can use?

To be more specific:

1. I'm trying to configure my virtual machine to run behind a proxy.
2. However, I want to use `cntlm` for this.
3. Therefore, in my vagrant script, the proxy setting has to be `127.0.0.1:3128`.
4. I can't do this at the first step because at that point, I need to install cntlm first. For this, the proxy has to be set to the real value : `myproxy.net`

My workaround for this was to run the first `vagrant up` command over WiFi (no proxy), install `cntlm` and everything, and then for every subsequent run (by this time, I'll switch to the proxy network), make sure that proxy is configured.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to run your provisioner after the vagrant box has booted you can do:

vagrant provision

source:
http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/

Comment: This won't work for me, because when provisioning, I need two different proxy settings for different steps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [vagrant-proxyconf plugin](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) so you should be to configure your proxy even by vagrant so to run everything during normal up/provision step (all in once)

you should be able to do something like this

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.proxy.http     = "http://192.168.0.2:3128/"
  config.proxy.https    = "http://192.168.0.2:3128/"

  # in any subsequent command the proxy is enabled

  # override parameter for the shell provisioner
  config.vm.define "instance" do |instance|
    instance.proxy.enabled = false
    instance.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.path = "install-puppet-modules.sh"
  end

end
```

in my case the `install-pupper-modules` script will download bunch of modules from puppet forge, it works as and if I comment the `instance.proxy.enabled = false` it cannot connect (I have no proxy configured)

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want different proxy settings for different steps of the provisioning.

Comment: @Sid, this is how I understood but with the plugin you should be able to override the setting for specific provision steps, editing the answer with an example (did not test but should work based on doc)

Comment: That looks promising. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. I get the error can't convert VagrantPlugins::Shell::Config to Array (VagrantPlugins::Shell::Config#to_ary gives Vagrant::Config::V2::DummyConfig) (TypeError)

Vagrantfile:19:in `block in <top (required)>'

My config looks like:
```
  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell, override|
    override.proxy.http = "http://myproxy.net:3128"
    override.proxy.https = "http://myproxy.net:3128"
    # in this provisioner proxy is set to specific value
    shell.path = "provision_scripts/configure_cntlm.sh"
  end
```

Comment: alright, I thought provision override would be the same as provider override but it appears to be a bit more tricky, [see the doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html) I'll update my example

Comment: @Sid, does it work now ? if so can you mark it as resolved, thanks !

Comment: this did not solve my purpose because within the shell privisioner, I didn't just have to disable proxy, but I needed a different one. In this case, it is always set to the outermost proxy. I think this is a limitation to how vagrant sets the machine up : it cannot provision for two different proxies in the same setup. Thanks for the help!